# How to most efficiently take in 10 different numbers from a user, add them to an array, and then output all of those numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, input

New to C++, I'm trying to make a program that takes in 10 different numbers, and it takes all of those numbers and adds them to an array list which prints them out at the end.

My code: (that doesn't work)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{


int numbers[10];
int input;

cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

   cin >> input;

   int numbers[i] = numbers + input;


    }

 cout << numbers;

}
```

When I run this and put in all 1's for all ten numbers, I expect to get an output like 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

but instead I get 0x7d88afc45630 which is weird and I'm not really sure why. I think it has to do with how I'm adding the numbers into the array list, which I'm not even sure how to do. I'd also like to be able to return the largest and smallest values of the list, but I need to figure this out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int numbers[i] = numbers + input;
```

It's converting the address the memory for numbers is at to an integer and adding it to input.

Do you just mean

```
numbers[i] = input;
```

On top of that, `cout << numbers` just prints out the memory location of numbers.

You probably want something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the output variable used as you don't need an array for this. Also, you don't need to put the data type before the variable name when assigning a value to it if you already declared that variable. See the modified code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int sum = 0;
  int input;

  cout << "Please enter ten numbers" << endl;

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    cin >> input;

    sum += input;
  }

  cout << sum;
}
```

If what you mean by "adding to an array" is putting the user input values to an array, just change these parts

```
  int sum = 0;
  :
    sum += input;
  :
  cout << sum;
```

to

```
  int numbers[10];
  :
    numbers[i] = input;
  :
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
  }
```

Comment: I don't think he wanted to sum them. --  "I expect to get an output like 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1"

Comment: @xaxxon yeah, just realized that as I got confused with the title